# Change UITextView text color with animation

Tags: iphone, animation, uitextview

Just a simple question.
Is it possible to change the text color of UITextView with a animation?

```
[UITextView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
[UITextView setAnimationDuration:2.0]; 
     textView.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];  
[UITextView commitAnimations];
```

Cheers!
- Martin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Martin Cote said textColor is not an animatable property.
I solved this with a change to the UItextView transparency instead.

```
[UITextView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
[UITextView setAnimationDuration:2.0]; 
     textView.alpha = 0.5f; 
[UITextView commitAnimations];
```

Thanks for your time.
/ martin

Answer (score 10):

Since iOS 4.0 you can now achieve this using `[UIView transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:]`

```
[UIView transitionWithView:textView
                  duration:0.5f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    textView.textColor = ...
                }
                completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 6):

The textColor is not an animatable property, so I don't think this will be feasible with the UITextView.